# Angular JS: $http.get e $routerParams

Tags: php, angularjs

Como utilizar o routeParams no $http.get para ele retornar apenas 1 objeto? 
Quero trazer apenas o objeto que tenha o mesmo ID passado no routeParams.

```
<a href="funcionario/edit/{{funcionario.id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="">
     Editar
</button>
```

Ao clicar em editar é direcionado para a página com o id correto.
Por exemplo: localhost/funcionario/edit/98. Uso as rotas abaixo.

```
var app = angular.module('funci',
                         ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','angular-confirm','ngSanitize' ]);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $routeProvider.when('/funcionarios', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/funcionarios.html',
    controller: 'FuncionariosController'
  });

  $routeProvider.when('/funcionario/novo', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/funcionario.html',
    controller: 'FuncionarioController'
  });

  $routeProvider.when('/funcionario/edit/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/funcionario.html',
    controller: 'FuncionarioController'
  });

  $routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/funcionarios'
  });

});
```

Nessa página, utilizo um controller diferente, chamado: funcionarioController.
É nesse controller que estou tentando da um console.log apenas no objeto de id passado no routeParams, porém não consigo obter.

```
app.controller('FuncionarioController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
  $scope.funcionario = {};

  $http.get('http://localhost/project-funci/api/getData.php'  + $routeParams.id)
  .then(function(funcionario) {
    $scope.funcionario = funcionario.data;
    console.log($scope.funcionario);
  });
```

O getdata.php:

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

$query = "select * from funcionario";

      if ($result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query))
         {
          while($row = $result->fetch_object())
          {
              foreach($row as $key => $col){
                 $col_array[$key] = utf8_encode($col);
              }
              $row_array[] =  $col_array;
          }
         echo json_encode($row_array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
      }
      mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
```

Resultado de getData.php

> [{"id":98,"cod_equipe":1,"cod_cargo":1,"nome":"Fulano","matricula":7414}

Atualmente, o console.log retorna impresso o html inteiro da página.

Por favor, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Você não está passando o parâmetro na URL do GET e nem recebendo o valor passado no script de select do php.

Um exemplo passando o parâmetro pelo GET seria assim:

```
('http://localhost/project-funci/api/getData.php?id='+ $routeParams.id)
```

Após isso, você poderá recebe-lo no PHP através da variavel global:

```
$getId = $_GET["id"];
```

E inseri-lo no query do sql.

```
$query = "select * from funcionario WHERE id = $getId";
```

Lembre-se de validar o campo antes de enviar e também validar no PHP.